# Solve recurrent ODE (elegantly?)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, perturbation-theory

It's about a simple recurrent ODE arising from a perturbation expansion
$$ \ddot y_0 + y_0  = 0, \\
\ddot y_n + y_n  = - \dot y_{n-1}, n \ge 1 $$
Now the first equation is easily solved with the ansatz $ y = e^{rt}$, resulting in $y_0 = A e^{it} + c.c.$. Theoretically the next solutions should be straightforward as the homogenous equation is the same and we can find the particular solution by variation of parameters, but the calculation seems a little (too) messy considering that the paper I'm reading just mentions the next solutions as $y_1 = - \frac{1}{2} A t e^{it} + c.c. $ and $y_2 = \frac{1}{8} A (t^2 - t)e^{it} + c.c. $ without further calculations or comments.

It feels like there's a faster way or a trick that I'm not aware of. Further, does the fact that the second solution is always equal to the complex conjugate simplify the calculation?

Comment: It is probably given without comment because it is very standard. Your method is fine, you could also guess a solution in the $n = 1$ case of the form $(At + B)e^{it}$ and $At^2 + Bt + C) e^{it}$ in the second. I believe this is called the method of undetermined coefficients.

Comment: The first solution should have the form $$A e^{it}+B e^{-it}$$